# Can we say ASP.NET is also MVC ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

ASP.NET also has UI, Event Handling and if good logic layer is implemented then the BLogic layer too. So that can we say its Model View Control style. Or its not that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. ASP.NET Web Forms is an implementation of Page Controller pattern.

[Chapter of Fowler's PoEAA about the Page Controller on Google Books](http://books.google.ru/books?id=FyWZt5DdvFkC&pg=PT360&lpg=PT360&dq=%22page+controller%22+pattern+fowler&source=bl&ots=eEFsZAVw4E&sig=dmfvIKgtP9Bxu4_U_BiemruJxeU&hl=ru&ei=5D8UTbbBC9HPjAe6iJ33BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

As a pattern MVC is more concerned with the idea that the controller orachastrates the view and the model.

In Web Forms there is no controller.  The View and the code behind (closest thing to a controller) are inherently the same thing, there is no separation of concerns.

Also depending on how you go about it, the model part of the MVC isn't necessarily your business logic.  For us its literally a View Model, and contains data relevant to the specific view only.  Business logic is handled in autonomous components.

With traditional web forms, I generally see the code behind (which is really part of the UI) having intimate knowledge of either business logic or data base access (and often a mixture of both).

Due to code behind it is hard to get away from this.

In my mind web forms create tightly coupled UI and business logic, and don't provide an easy way to enforce separation of concerns.

I'd say web forms does not adhere to the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In `MVC`, all requests are routed to a `Controller`.

In `ASP.NET` all requests are routed to a Page. That is a `View` and not `Controller`.

`ASP.NET` better matches with `MVP` rather than `MVC`. Reason being, in `MVP`, a `View` is supposed to process user inputs/requests and pass it on to appropriate `Presenters`.